# regex to find end_time from - "end_time": null,

Tags: regex

I'm not able to create regex to find end_time from api response "end_time": null,

I'm able to find ": null" using regex but how to find end_time by searching null value in api response?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want a regex that matches the string preceding `: null`? Is that what you want?

Comment: It sounds like your API is returning JSON. Why don't you use the JSON parser in your programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Assumptions

1. "end_time: null" is a single line without leading or trailing whitespace.
2. You are looking for any line of the form "*somestring*: null" where *somestring* is your target match.

---

## Solutions

### solution 1

```
^(.*?)(?=: null)
```

This regex will match everything from the start of a line to before the *first* `: null` on that same line.

### solution 2

```
^(.*)(?=: null)
```

This regex will match everything from the start of a line to before the *last* `: null` on that same line.

### solution 3

```
\w+(?=: null)
```

This regex will match a single word that immediately precedes an instance of `: null`.

```
\w+(?=\s*: null)
```

This regex is the same as the above, except that it allows whitespace between the word and `: null`.

```
\w+(?=[^\S$]*: null)
```

This regex is the same as the above, except that it allows only whitespace that does not end the line (e.g. disallows `\n`).